# Bash/pv Outputting "^M" at the end of each line

Tags: bash, debian, pv

Super simple, but I have NO IDEA how to fix this.  I have a super simple pv line (or so I thought) that writes to a file, but the output appends "^M" to the end of each line which the tail command doesn't interpret properly.

To explain, I'm writing an image to a compute module (CM3 or CM4) with pv and outputting the stderr to a temp file I can read from a dialog box lower in the code.

For some reason, the tailboxbg I'm using doesn't realize it's changing and just keeps the first line posted (since it's appended with "^M" which is not a newline) but I never specify anywhere to add that to the end of the line.

The code:

```
pv -teabf -s "$copySize" "$copyImage" > "devCompMod" 2> _temp &
```

The _temp file:

```
 429MiB 0:00:01 [ 429MiB/s] ETA 0:00:33^M 819MiB 0:00:02 [ 408MiB/s] ETA 0:00:34^M 880MiB 0:00:03 [ 292MiB/s] ETA 0:00:47^M 939MiB 0:00:04 [ 234MiB/s] ETA 0:00:59^M 999MiB 0:00:05 [ 199MiB/s] ETA 0:01:09^M 1.34GiB 0:00:06 [ 229MiB/s] ETA 0:00:59^M
pv: write failed: No space left on device
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm losing my mind here.

I tried different redirections, but I have no idea how to pipe stderr through something else without completely screwing up my fileread, since it's running in a subshell ("&").

**EDIT:**  A combination of two suggestions on the accepted answer ended up working for me.  It's my fault, I didn't add enough of the surrounding code, it was way too precise.

Anyways for anyone who would need this in the future, I ended up using:

```
pv -F $'%b %t %a %e\n' -f -s "$cpSize" "$cpImage" > "$devTofu" 2> _temp &
```

And reading the lines directly from `_temp` (instead of using `_pvoutput`) by using:

```
lastLines="$(tail -n 2 _temp | tr -d $'\r\n')"
```

I ended up using `-n 2` because tail had a hard time getting the last line since it always began with an `^M` and ended with a `\n`.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: `^M` is `\r`. Unix uses `\n` for line endings, MSDOS and Windows use `\r\n`. Use a tool like `dos2unix` or a global search and replace to get rid of the extra `^M`. Then configure VS Code to not add them.

Comment: It looks like the line ending is _just_ a `\r`, which is a classic Mac line ending

Comment: I read that as well, but nowhere in the chain do I use MSDOS or Windows (I code on OSX and my production environment is on Debian).  Also, it's PV that's generating the `^M`s to the file. It's only ever written on by PV and gets deleted after use.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `pv` uses carriage return in its status output because it's intended to go to a terminal, and have each update overwrite the previous one on the same line rather than going to a new line.

Comment: So in summary, why on Earth are you using `pv` at all if you are writing the output to a file?

Comment: I'm writing the output to a disk, and since I'm running the command in a subshell to pipe into a `dialog`, for gauge and tailing of the logfile, I needed the stderr (where pv prints status messages) to be redirected somewhere else.  My issue with it was that the format for it is to stream the output, not read line by line, which I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with dos or mac. It is just that it really intends to add a `\r` to have a status line updating, instead of repeating them many times. I do that often in my own code.

One solution could be to add another command to replace `\r` by `\n`.

```bash
pv -teabf -s "$copySize" "$copyImage" 2>&1 > "devCompMod" | tr $'\r' $'\n'
```

Btw, that's how you pipe stderr. Just redirect it to stdout. But be sure, of course to redirect stdout on something else. Which you already did.

The thing that appears unnatural to most people with this is the order.
Instinct could say that I should `cmd > stdout.txt 2>&1 | stderrfilter`.
That is, first get take the original content from stdout to a file, and now that this content has be "displaced", use the now empty stdout to hold stderr with `2>&1`, and then pipe it.

But that is not what redirections mean.  It is not content that you displace. It is filedescriptors. `a>&b`, is the bash version of `dup2(b,a)`

So see it more some sort of variables holding the destination of outputs. Whose initial values are `dest1 = STDOUT`, `dest2 = STDERR`. Everything that is printed to stdout goes to `dest1`. Everything that is printed to stderr goes to `dest2`. Unless your redirect something. `> outfile.txt`, changes `dest1 = outfile.txt`. `2>&1` changes `dest2` to whatever is in `dest1`, like `dest2 = dest1`.

So, doing `cmd > stdout.txt 2>&1 | filter`, is like `dest1=stdout.txt ; dest2=dest1`. So that order doesn't work. It means that every outputs goes (mixed) to stdout.txt.

Instead `cmd 2>&1 > stdout.txt | filter`, is like `dest2=dest1; dest1=stdout.txt` so first changes `dest2` to initial value of `dest1`, that is STDOUT then `dest1` to `stdout.txt`. So std output of `cmd` goest to `stdout.txt`, and its err output goes to STDOUT, that is, to the pipe.

Of course, that is not really how it works. But that is schematically how to understand in which order to use the pipes and redirections. Again, think of them as variables, holding destinations. That you have to assign in a logical order. And not as content, that you have to displace.

And anyway, the correct order to redirect standard output to a file and standard error to a pipe is `pv ... 2>&1 > outfile | filter`

#### Another way

If you don't want to struggle with redirection, another way could be to tell `pv` to add a `\n` itself, by creating the output string with format option.

```bash
pv -F $'%t %e %a %b\n' -f -s "$copySize" "$copyImage" > "devCompMod"
```

But it is not ideal. First of all, it doesn't remove the `\r` (on a terminal, the only consequence is that the cursor is at the beginning of the line, not the end. I suppose most tool parsing lines wouldn't care neither. But you never know). It just add a `\n`.

And secondly, I suppose that in reality you would like to redirect the result anyway, since I take your objective is to feed another tool with the progress indication, that is stderr of pv. Your `_temp` was probably a fix because you couldn't redirect stderr in a pipe... but now that you know how to, I surmise you wouldn't use that `_temp` anymore.

But, well, if it works for you, then it is probably preferable over adding another command in your pipe chain (besides, I don't know if `tr` doesn't add a latency)

## So, tl;dr

```bash
pv -F $'%t %e %a %b\n' -f -s "$copySize" "$copyImage" > "devCompMod" 2> _temp
```

or

```bash
pv -teabf -s "$copySize" "$copyImage" 2>&1 > "devCompMod" | tr $'\r' $'\n' > _temp
```

if you want the progress into `_temp`. Preferably the first; the 2nd if the `\r` that are still (in addition to added `\n`) in the 1st output are a problem.

And if you want to redirect that output to a dialog command, instead of using a temp file.

```bash
pv -F $'%t %e %a %b\n' -f -s "$copySize" "$copyImage" 2>&1 > "devCompMod" | dialog
```

or

```bash
pv -teabf -s "$copySize" "$copyImage" 2>&1 > "devCompMod" | tr $'\r' $'\n' | dialog
```

Comment: Ho-ly, thanks for the explanation!  I will give this a go and come back with a status update.  I found a workaround way of doing it but it's waaaaay worse than this, so I'll give this a try once I get to my production machine.

Edit: I'm using the _temp file because that command runs in a subshell, and the dialog that uses it as a gauge has its own while loop that listens to the subprocess, sanitizes the data, calculates the percentage left and pipes it into the dialog option.